# Exclude directories from tar archive with a .tarignore file

Tags: linux, archive, tar, gitignore, ignore

In a similar way to `.gitignore`, is it possible to do that a `.tarignore` file in a subdirectory makes it excluded from archive when doing

```
tar cfjvh backup.tar.bz2 .
```

(I know the `--exclude` parameter of `tar` but here it's not what I want).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the [`--exclude-ignore=.tarignore`](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/exclude.html#index-exclude_002dignore) option causes Tar to use `.tarignore` files in a similar way that git uses `.gitignore` files. Use the same syntax as you would usually use in `.gitignore` files, so if you want to ignore all sub-directories and files in a particular directory, add a `.gitignore` file with `*` to that directory. For example:

```
$ find dir
dir
dir/a
dir/b
dir/c
dir/dir1
dir/dir1/1a
dir/dir1/1b
dir/dir2
dir/dir2/2a
dir/dir2/2b
$ echo "*" > dir/dir1/.tarignore
$ tar -c --exclude-ignore=.tarignore -vjf archive.tar.bz2 dir
dir/
dir/a
dir/b
dir/c
dir/dir1/
dir/dir2/
dir/dir2/2a
dir/dir2/2b
```

If you want to ignore all directories that have an empty `.tarignore` file, take a look at the [`--exclude-tag-all=.tarignore`](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/exclude.html#index-exclude_002dtag_002dall) option.

```
$ find dir
dir
dir/a
dir/b
dir/c
dir/dir1
dir/dir1/1a
dir/dir1/1b
dir/dir2
dir/dir2/2a
dir/dir2/2b
$ touch dir/dir1/.tarignore
$ tar -c --exclude-tag-all=.tarignore -vjf archive.tar.bz2 dir
tar: dir/dir1/: contains a cache directory tag .tarignore; directory not dumped
dir/
dir/a
dir/b
dir/c
dir/dir2/
dir/dir2/2a
dir/dir2/2b
```

Also take a look at the `--exclude-tag=` and `--exclude-tag=` options, which are variations which have slightly different behaviors.

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like

```
$ COPYFILE_DISABLE=true tar -c --exclude-from=.tarignore -vzf archiveName.tar.gz
```

The breakdown:-

- Reason for `COPYFILE_DISABLE=true`is for making sure files starting with `._` are not included in the `.tar` file made. Enable it permanently adding `export COPYFILE_DISABLE=true` to `~/.bash_profile` on your Mac if you frequently do `tar` operations.
- `–exclude-from=.tarignore:` Ignore all files and folders listed in `.tarignore`

You can have the following content in your `.tarignore`, here is mine

```
$ cat .tarignore
.DS_Store
.git
.gitignore
```

Comment: Thanks but it seems it's not exactly what I want. I want to put just an *empty* `.tarignore` file in each dir that I want to be bypassed. Do you see what I mean? I'm going to have maybe 10 or 20 such `.tarignore` files in each folder that should be ignored.

Answer (score 6):

I just found out that git has a tool to package the tracked files itself:
[`git archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive). Using that is probably the easiest way.

EDIT: If you want to make a package out of files / data that is not yet commited (but tracked), using `tar -czf files.tar.gz $(git ls-files)` works.

Comment: Cannot be simpler. Works perfectly.