# Exclude directories from tar with .tarignore file (#2)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, tar, system-administration

This is a bit of a repeat post based on [this post of a similar name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514510/exclude-directories-from-tar-archive-with-a-tarignore-file)

I cannot get this method to work so I'm trying to figure out if I'm doing something wrong or if this just doesn't work.

I created `.tarignore` in my `~` home directory

Inside `.tarignore` I've tried a variety of things, this is the current attempt:

```
dirname/
dirname/*
/home/ubuntu/dirname/
/home/ubuntu/dirname/*
*.js
```

Then I run this command from the `~` home dir

`tar -zcvf cur.tar.gz /home/ubuntu/dirname --exclude-ignore-recursive=.tarignore`

I believe that this should result in absolutely nothing getting tar'd yet the verbose output is showing me that files in `dirname/` are being tar'd as are `.js` files.

Been stuck on this for a bit, hoping I'm just doing something silly :/

Edit: I'm running this on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I suggest to use `--exclude-from=`.

Comment: How come? Just tried it, seeing the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was doing something wrong - incorrect order of the arguments. I also switched to `--exclude-from` per @Cyrus' comment and it seems to work fine.

`tar -zcvf cur.tar.gz --exclude-from=.tarignore /home/ubuntu/dirname`

And a sample from the `.tarignore` file:

```
# Ignore these paths
build/*
node_modules/*
.git/*
```